# How to ignore warning when Batch Processing files in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am running a Macro written in VBA for Batch Processing files, but for some of the files and Alert Warning is shown when they are being processed. I would like for this Alert Warning to be avoided so the porgram can proceed with the Processing. What code should be appropriate for that ?

Comment: What is popping up the alert - Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Toggling DisplayAlerts should stop it

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```